# Stuck in GNU GRUB with disabled keyboard

Tags: boot, usb, grub2, grub

Neither on boot nor in the gnu GRUB menu USB keyboard and mouse don't work. And the menu doesn't have a timeout to let me in into any OS I got.

Typicaly this such troubles aren't that bad, cause you can go to the firmware settings and change something, you can boot from USB and again solve the problem, or you stuck in the grub console, but your keyboard works so you can run commands

But in my case I can't do anything:

1. Can't go to firmware settings cause keyboard doesn't work so I can't push some button to enter it
2. Can't choose anything in the grub menu, cause again a keyboard doesn't work
3. Can't boot from USB cause it's not prior by default and I can't change it now
4. Can't just wait for a selected by default choice to be used cause there's no a timeout

Please, help

*P.s.: my machine has kinda latest hardware and the keyboard either is like 1 year old, so I got no ancient hardware that doesn't support some new stuff it could have not support*

Comment: It doesn't sound like a driver issue, as OS isn't booted. I have only seen a USB keyboard not working on a 20 year-old machine, which only accepted PS/2, yet never seen a computer with a functional keyboard not functioning. Could you try another one (or PS/2 as a last resort if it is a desktop)?

Comment: @cbugk, I doesn't have PS/2, and yeah, it's a desktop

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Could you check if USB ports on the motherboard actually work, they might have been broken (e.g. thumb or HDD drives with blinking LEDs). Also could you try removing the CR2032 battery (BIOS battery), reattaching PSU cable after 10-20 seconds, and booting up. This had saved me while overclocking RAM, I know it sounds irrelevant but this is to reset BIOS options and is worth a try.

Comment: I'm running into this ; the current suspect is the keyboard supporting N-key rollover, which has a different key impulse reporting structure to standard HID. It's a QMK firmware, so I'm going to try reflashing it with NKRO disabled. USB HID devices are supposed to revert to "boot protocol" (6KRO) when signalled, and GRUB does seem to have code to do this ... so the question is, is GRUB doing it wrong, or the keyboard doing it wrong, or something else ...